# NSDictionary lookup table with 200k entries - iPhone

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary

I have a simple lookup table, which consists of the following structure:

int | string

- given an int, I want to return a string. However I have to use a lookup table as there is no correlation between the int and the string.

What is the most efficient and fastest way to implement this on the iPhone in Objective-C?

E.g.
// However will 200k values take too long to load and take up too much memory?
NSString *value = [lookupTable objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:key]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing how large your strings are, you should almost certainly be looking at coredata for this sort of thing. It'll work a treat for those sort of numbers and will keep your memory footprint low.

There's quite a nice [coredata tutorial here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started) and of course [copious Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Agreed with the first answer here.  Coredata is the way to go if your dictionary has that many values.  It would take a long time to load that many rows into memory on an i* and would probably push other apps out of memory, which would impact the user experience for the customer.